# Unity VR Detect if object is being held

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I am using the XR Interaction Manager in Unity VR. The player can hold objects when pressing the trigger button of the hands (the interactable object has the component XR Grab Interactable).

I want to detect if the object is being held or not, so when the player lets go of the object, something happens.

I can't simply detect if the trigger is being held, because that would simply give true even though the object isn't actually being held in that hand.

How should I know if an object is being held? Is there a boolean somewhere?

Comment: Checking [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@2.1/manual/interactable-events.html), it looks like there's an `Activated` event invoked when the object is grabbed, and a `Deactivated` event invoked when the object is dropped. Have you tried subscribing to these events to manage your held state?